# How to run an elf executable from memory (directly)

Tags: c, linux, elf

Load a PE file on windows is very simple, like this

```
image_base = allocate memory
copy whole PE file into image_base

fix RVA from 
OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC]
OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT]

run PE
((void(*)())(image_base + optional_header->AddressOfEntryPoint))();
```

but load an ELF on linux seems very difficult .

I downloaded almost all  "ELF Loader" project from github
, none of those are works (condition: without change entry).

I am very sure run an ELF from memory is possible (no memfd_create), some packers like UPX did it.

please give me some help.

Comment: @Frank, what version of `exec` are you thinking of that relies on a file descriptor instead of a path?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Arg, you are right, for some reason I was sure there was one, so there's a few additional hoops that need to be jumped through...

Comment: I am inclined to agree that there is no easy way to do this, at least in the sense of running one program in the memory space of another (without replacing that other), as seems to be the intent.  Certainly none of the `exec`-family functions will do that.

Comment: UPX have documented their way: https://github.com/upx/upx/blob/devel/doc/elf-to-mem.txt